# componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate error: Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got error of

```
Invariant Violation: Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch.
```

when using 2 lifecycle method of react to call APIs.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const action_id = this.context.router.params.action_id
    if(action_id) {
        this.getMsg(action_id)
    }
}

componentDidUpdate(prevContext) {
    const action_id = this.context.router.params.action_id
    if(!isEqual(prevContext.params.action_id, action_id)){
        this.getMsg(action_id)
    }
}
```

Above step are needed, the code in componentDidMount call an endpoint to get a list msg, the componentDidUpdate detect whether user click back or navigate around, then call the Api. I've no clue how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The dispatcher cannot dispatch another action in middle of an action.
To avoid this you can use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in your action creater .

Eg:

```
 return new Promise.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            resolve();
        }).then(() => {
            dispatcher.dispatch(your action );
        }).catch();
```